# Is there any pattern in prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Do a pattern exist in set of prime numbers or is there any expression for a prime number?? I am unable to find any relation between prime numbers

Comment: Depends what you mean by a "pattern".  As for "expression for a prime number", see e.g. [Formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes)

Comment: See [Prime number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint -

All primes greater than 3 should be in the form $6k \pm 1$.

Hope now you are able to find pattern.

Comment: I to found the same ans in a book but could not found its derivation, can it be proved?,

Comment: @vish Yes it can be proved. $6k\pm 1$ is the same as $6k + 1 \cup (6k - 1=6k+5)$. That leaves 4 other cases: $6k+0, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+4$. Each of those four cases is divisible by 2 or 3. Also note, that not all number of the form $6k\pm 1$ are prime. Rather all primes are of that form. Finally, another, a slightly more selective pattern is all primes are $\equiv \mod 30$ one of the following: $1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29$. You can also come up with a similar, but more refined list $\equiv \mod 210$